# Xamarin Forms: how to implement platform specific code

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I do have a Xamarin Forms project where I want Android, iOS and WinPhone as targets. (Right now I only look at Android.)

I am having trouble playing Audio and think I will need to implement it differently on each device.

I started with adding this code in the app.cs of the shared project

```
#if __ANDROID__
    MediaPlayer _player;
    _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resources.Raw.bear); // "Resources.Raw.bear");
    _player.Start();
#endif
```

but found that I cannot really reference the bear.wav, so I think I have to add the bear.wav for each project/platform and also handle the playing code separately. (See also http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/play_audio/ )

Unfortunately, I could not find a sample - or any documentation - on how to do this.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/ is the closest I could find, but it seems to be highly focused on renderers.

What I thought I would do would be to define an abstract class in the shared project (some simple class, just with a *void play* method), and use it, and have the specific implementations in each platform-project. How to go about this?

Comment: As far as I know, your resources have to be added to each platform.  You cannot add them to the shared project/pcl and share them.

Comment: try adding it as an embedded resource. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write device platform specific code in Xamarin.Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251020/write-device-platform-specific-code-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like
[Write device platform specific code in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251020/write-device-platform-specific-code-in-xamarin-forms)
answers the question - which is not so much a Xamarin Forms question as a Visual Studio shared project question and can be solved by creating an interface/abstract class and then implementing that for each platform and injecting the implementation.