# Xamarin Forms TelephonyManager, which assembly to reference

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm looking to get the device phone number using C# in Xamarin Forms.

I had found this code in another post, but I'm unsure out which assembly I should reference to use it, can anyone tell me?

thanks

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Android Telephony Manager](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager/) class, which can be found in the `Android.Telephony` namespace.

Bear in mind that this is platform-specific and can only be used in an Android project. If you are trying to create a cross-platform solution, then I suggest that you create an interface in your core project which includes a method such as GetPhoneInfo, and then implement this interface in two platform-specific classes which use the correct platform-specific code to retrieve the details you are after. See [this answer for more information on writing platform specific code in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24251871/15904).