# Setting text to clipboard Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So i am trying to set text of my "Editor" to clipboard. I am reading alot on forums such as xamarin, where people is saying that this is a bug and cannot be done? Is this true?

Because when i am trying to set text to clipboard i get this error "Specified cast is not valid" on the first line.

```
private void I_Tapping(object sender, MR.Gestures.LongPressEventArgs e)
{
 var clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)Context.ClipboardService;
 var clip = ClipData.NewPlainText("Link", editorLinkText.Text);
 clipBoard.PrimaryClip = clip;
}
```

I tried to implement this from a xamarin forum site but the "Forms" after (ClipboardManager) is not found for me.

```
 // Get the Clipboard Manager
 var clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ClipboardService);

// Create a new Clip
Android.Content.ClipData clip = Android.Content.ClipData.NewPlainText(title, text);

// Copy the text
clipboardManager.PrimaryClip = clip;
```

This is a crossplatform project, hens why its not working with clipboardmanager because the .cs file is in the top portion of the project?

I couldn't find the other sites i was looking at but this is one site where they say that this is bugged. But if it isn't, Help me out on this :)
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6402/clipboard-copy-paste-problem

King Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugins.Clipboard/

Really good when dealing with crossplatforming. Download it and use this code and you will be good to go.

```
using Plugin.Clipboard;

private void I_Tapping(object sender, MR.Gestures.LongPressEventArgs e)
{
    CrossClipboard.Current.SetText(editorLinkText.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a solution that requires no additional Nuget package.

To get & set Clipboard for official supported platforms of Xamarin (i.e Android, iOS, UWP), you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/clipboard):

To set text to the Clipboard:

```
await Clipboard.SetTextAsync("Hello World");
```

To read text from the Clipboard:

```
var text = await Clipboard.GetTextAsync();
```

These won't work for other platforms that aren't officially supported by Xamarin (e.g WPF, I prefer WPF over UWP for windows because WPF can run for other Windows version, while UWP can only be run on Windows 10-and later). So if you want to make it works on WPF, you can do this: [Write device platform specific code for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24251871/4608491) to get/set clipboard for WPF.

Assume you want to develop WPF as one of your other platforms.

In Xamarin Share project, create an Interface IMJHeeHeeYouWantAPartyClipboard and implement the default XamarinClipboard for this interface.

```
public interface IMJHeeHeeYouWantAPartyClipboard
{
    bool HasText { get; }
    Task<string> GetTextAsync();
    Task SetTextAsync(string value);
}

class XamarinClipboard : IMJHeeHeeYouWantAPartyClipboard
{
    public bool HasText => Clipboard.HasText;

    public async Task<string> GetTextAsync()
    {
        return await Clipboard.GetTextAsync();
    }

    public async Task SetTextAsync(string value)
    {
        await Clipboard.SetTextAsync(value);
    }
}
```

In WPF project, implement the WpfClipboard for this interface:

```
class WpfClipboard : IMJHeeHeeYouWantAPartyClipboard
{
    public bool HasText => Clipboard.ContainsText();

    public Task<string> GetTextAsync()
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736803/set-clipboard-in-async-method
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Most usages will require a message pump, which can be
                // started by calling Application.Run() at an appropriate point.
                tcs.SetResult(Clipboard.GetText());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                tcs.SetException(e);
            }
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public Task SetTextAsync(string value)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(value);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Now this is how we put this into use.

In the Xamarin Share project, let App class (App.xaml.cs) receive this Clipboard object from other platforms if needed:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static IMJHeeHeeYouWantAPartyClipboard s_clipboard;
    public static IMJHeeHeeYouWantAPartyClipboard Clipboard => s_clipboard;

    public App(IMJHeeHeeYouWantAPartyClipboard value = null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (value != null)
            s_clipboard = value;
        else
            s_clipboard = new XamarinClipboard();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
    //....
```

In WPF project, pass the WpfClipboard object into the App object of Xamarin (in file MainWindow.xaml.cs, assume you've properly setup this file for Xamarin):

```
public partial class MainWindow : FormsApplicationPage
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new Calculator.App(new WpfClipboard()));
    }
}
```