Visual Studio extension to set Clipboard content
I am trying to write a simple Visual Studio extension that will build a branch name based on Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard contents. The basic idea is to get the top two items in Clipboard stack, combine them and put the result back in the Clipboard, from where I can paste it on the New Branch window.
Getting and combining the items is easy; the problem is when I try to put the result in the Clipboard.
I am using the Visual Studio Extensibility extension, C#, target framework is .NET 8.0, target OS is Windows version 10.0.22621.0.
First attempt:
public override async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(IClientContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        var clipItems = (await Clipboard.GetHistoryItemsAsync()).Items.Take(2).ToArray();
        var taskNumber = (await clipItems[1].Content.GetTextAsync()).ToString().Trim();
        var taskName = (await clipItems[0].Content.GetTextAsync()).ToString().Trim();
        var branchName = $"feature/{taskNumber}-{taskName}";

        DataPackage dataPackage = new();
        dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
        dataPackage.SetText(branchName);
        Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);  // Problem here!
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Extensibility.Shell().ShowPromptAsync(ex.Message, PromptOptions.OK, cancellationToken);
    }
}

I get an exception when Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage) is executed:

Stack:
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|39_0(Int32 hr)
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.IClipboardStaticsMethods.SetContent(IObjectReference _obj, DataPackage content)
   at Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.SetContent(DataPackage content)
   at BranchNameExtension.CommandBranchName.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\repos\_My Apps\_Extensions\VS Extensions 2 Solution\BranchNameExtension\CommandBranchName.cs:line 59

According to some sources in StackOverflow, the SetContent should be executed in a thread other than the UI thread. So I changed to code to:
public override async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(IClientContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        var clipItems = (await Clipboard.GetHistoryItemsAsync()).Items.Take(2).ToArray();
        var taskNumber = (await clipItems[1].Content.GetTextAsync()).ToString().Trim();
        var taskName = (await clipItems[0].Content.GetTextAsync()).ToString().Trim();
        var branchName = $"feature/{taskNumber}-{taskName}";

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            DataPackage dataPackage = new();
            dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
            dataPackage.SetText(branchName);
            Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Extensibility.Shell().ShowPromptAsync(ex.Message, PromptOptions.OK, cancellationToken);
    }
}


I tried some variations on the Task theme and also using System.Windows.Clipboard for setting the clipboard text, with the same results.
Any suggestions? Thanks!
UPDATE:
I was able to achieve my goal by using Matthew Watson suggestion and using System.Windows.Clipboard to paste the results, although I don't thing this is an elegant solution:
    public override async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(IClientContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        var clipItems = (await Clipboard.GetHistoryItemsAsync()).Items.Take(2).ToArray();
        var taskNumber = (await clipItems[1].Content.GetTextAsync()).ToString().Trim();
        var taskName = (await clipItems[0].Content.GetTextAsync()).ToString().Trim();
        var branchName = $"feature/{taskNumber}-{taskName}";

        await STATask.RunAsync(() => System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(branchName));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}


Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56737049/106159

What is the detailed error code in this situation? :)

@MatthewWatson No, I still get the System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '' error.
